# AWS S3 - com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Request ARN is invalid

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make my android app download images from AWS S3. However, the following exception keeps coming up:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Request ARN is invalid (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 3481bd5f-1db2-11e5-8442-cb6f713243b6)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:710)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:385)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
            at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:875)
            at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:496)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithSts(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:671)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:555)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:503)
            at com.application.app.utils.helper.S3Utils.getCredProvider(S3Utils.java:35)
            at com.application.app.utils.helper.S3Utils.getS3Client(S3Utils.java:45)
            at com.application.app.integration.volley.CustomImageRequest.parseNetworkError(CustomImageRequest.java:73)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.parseAndDeliverNetworkError(NetworkDispatcher.java:144)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:135)
```

I have a bucket and an identity pool. Also, created required roles.

My Cognito_APPUnauth_Role has the following INLINE POLICY:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1435504517000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a java class named S3Utils that has some helper methods.

```
public class S3Utils {
    private static AmazonS3Client sS3Client;

    private static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider sCredProvider;

    public static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredProvider(Context context){
        if (sCredProvider == null) {
            sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context,
                    Definitions.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
                    Definitions.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
                    Definitions.COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH,
                    null,
                    Regions.US_EAST_1
            );
        }

        sCredProvider.refresh();
        return sCredProvider;
    }

    public static String getPrefix(Context context) {
        return getCredProvider(context).getIdentityId() + "/";
    }

    public static AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context) {
        if (sS3Client == null) {
            sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getCredProvider(context));
        }
        return sS3Client;
    }

    public static String getFileName(String path) {
        return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }

    public static boolean doesBucketExist() {
        return sS3Client.doesBucketExist(Definitions.BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
    }

    public static void createBucket() {
        sS3Client.createBucket(Definitions.BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
    }

    public static void deleteBucket() {
        String name = Definitions.BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        List<S3ObjectSummary> objData = sS3Client.listObjects(name).getObjectSummaries();
        if (objData.size() > 0) {
            DeleteObjectsRequest emptyBucket = new DeleteObjectsRequest(name);
            List<DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion> keyList = new ArrayList<DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion>();
            for (S3ObjectSummary summary : objData) {
                keyList.add(new DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion(summary.getKey()));
            }
            emptyBucket.withKeys(keyList);
            sS3Client.deleteObjects(emptyBucket);
        }
        sS3Client.deleteBucket(name);
    }
}
```

Part of the method where the exception occurs, in CustomImageRequest.java:

```
s3Client = S3Utils.getS3Client(context);
            ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(Definitions.BUCKET_NAME).withPrefix(this.urlToRetrieve));
            List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaries = objects.getObjectSummaries();
            //This isn't just an id, it is a full picture name in S3 bucket.
            for (S3ObjectSummary summary : objectSummaries)
            {
                String key = summary.getKey();
                if (!key.equals(this.urlToRetrieve)) continue;
                S3ObjectInputStream content = s3Client.getObject(Definitions.BUCKET_NAME, key).getObjectContent();
                try {
                    this.s3Image = IOUtils.toByteArray(content);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                return new Object();
            }
```

What am I doing wrong that causes this exception to be thrown every time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there might be an error in the role ARN you specified.  A role ARN should look something like

arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-1:ACCOUNTNUMBER:identitypool/us-east-1:UUID

If it is misspelled, or part is left off you may get the error.  You may also want to consider user the new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider constructor.

```
sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context,
                Definitions.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
                Regions.US_EAST_1
        );
```

However note that you will have to make sure that you have specified your role ARN in the Cognito console, but it should help prevent this issue in the future.

Edited for clarity, formatting, and added that you need to modify your ARN in the console if using new constructor.